# What's the exact widget of an android's vertical view of information flow?

Tags: android, user-interface, scroll, widget

Just like these:

http://cyrilmottier.com/media/2012/03/the-pull-to-refresh-an-anti-ui-pattern-on-android/pull_to_refresh.jpg

http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-q-BHPNNbM5E/UC1aFgpY54I/AAAAAAAAI0s/KRjpTwVMQ3o/s400/Quick+Return+(1).png

I want to implement a twitter-like UI, but I don't know what the child widget(each small grid with rich text and an icon, maybe there is a small button at top right corner) and the whole scrollable view are. Can `ScrollView` implement this? Or there are other libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of those screenshots would appear to show a `ListView` with added third-party pull-to-refresh logic.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out that there is a library implementing the details:
https://github.com/shardul/Android/tree/master/NowLayout/src/com/shardul/nowlayout
And a pull-to-refresh library:
https://code.google.com/p/pull-to-refresh-view/

Combining them, I created a greate Google-Now-like UI.